# Сравнение дата фреймов по нескольким столбцам одновременно в r

Tags: r

У меня есть две date frames и мне нужно сравнить строки из df1 по столбцам Syllable и Duration со строками из df2 так, чтобы те строки, которых нет в df1 удалились и фильтрованные строки Pitch добавились в df1:

```
df1$Pitch <- df2$Pitch[match(df2$Syllable[df2$Duration], df1$Syllable[df1$Duration])]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так чтобы моя новая таблица выглядила как:

```
    Syllable Duration Pitch
     bIs     0.18    78.533
     zEks    0.34    67.304
     b@n     0.11    69.172
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
libarary(dplyr)
# создаем тестовые наборы данных
df1 <- data.frame (Syllable = as.character(c("bls", "zEks", "b@n")), Duration = c(0.18, 0.34, 0.11), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame (Syllable = as.character(c("bls", "zEks", "b2:", "@n", "b@n")), Duration = c(0.18, 0.34, 0.19, 0.19, 0.11), Pith = c(78.533, 67.304, 65.003, 65.038, 69.172), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

> ```
>   df1
>   Syllable Duration
> 1      bls     0.18
> 2     zEks     0.34
> 3      b@n     0.11
>
>    df2
>    Syllable Duration   Pith
> 1       bls     0.18 78.533
> 2      zEks     0.34 67.304
> 3       b2:     0.19 65.003
> 4        @n     0.19 65.038
> 5       b@n     0.11 69.172
> ```

```
#объединяем данные
dfr  <- left_join(df1, df2, by = "Syllable")
```

> ```
> dfr
>     Syllable Duration.x Duration.y   Pith
>  1      bls       0.18       0.18 78.533
>  2     zEks       0.34       0.34 67.304
>  3      b@n       0.11       0.11 69.172
> ```

```
# удаляем Duration.y
dfr  <- select(dfr, -Duration.y)
# переименовываем Duration.x в Duration
dfr  <-  rename(dfr, Duration = Duration.x)

# финал
```

> ```
> dfr
>   Syllable Duration   Pith
> 1      bls     0.18 78.533
> 2     zEks     0.34 67.304
> 3      b@n     0.11 69.172
> ```

PS.
Краткая и емкая шпаргалка по манипуляции данными с помощью пакета [dplyr](https://ugoproto.github.io/ugo_r_doc/dplyr.pdf)